# Fetch API CALL in reactJS with self-signed certificate for website

Tags: reactjs

Developing a webapp application in reactJS using third party API. API contain https self signed certificate. while calling the API its showing IN_SECURE_CONNECTION error. How to send self-signed certificate in fetch method while integrating.

Comment: tried axios for fetching?

Comment: Yes..that also not working, showing same error.

Comment: I'm looking for answer as well